# How to stop MySQL from replicating CREATE TABLE... on Slave for ignored databases

Tags: mysql, replication

Mine is a simple MySQL Master-Slave setup, with `--binlog-do-db` option as discussed in [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html).

As per the documentation, logs are written for DDL statements for all databases irrespective of '`--binlog-do-db`'.

Is there any way to stop this??

Comment: you may also need to replicate-ignore-db on to slave to avoid replicating db..are you using that?

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that, when it comes to DML statments binlog-do-db and replicate-ignore-db are working fine, but not for DDL

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using, and are you using statement based or row based replication?

Comment: Row based Replication, for MySQL 5.7.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binlog_do_db = dbname` says to replicate any statement *when the default database is dbname*.  So be careful what `USE` statement precedes the statement:

```
USE non_repl_db;
CREATE TABLE ...;
```